# How does Javascript pass values from a "super class" to a "child class"

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, constructor

I'm well aware that javascript is not a class based language.

With that being said here is an example of (one of the ways) we do inheritance in JavaScript:

```js
function Person(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    Person.prototype.introduceSelf = function() {
        console.log("My name is " + this.name + " and I'm " + this.age);
    }

    function Employee(name, age, employeeID) {
        Person.call(this, name, age);
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

    Employee.prototype.sayEmployeeID = function() {
        console.log('My Employee ID is: ' + this.employeeID);
    }

    var joe = new Employee('Joe', 22, 42);
    joe.introduceSelf() // returns: My name is joe and I'm 22
    joe.sayEmployeeID() // returns: My Employee ID is: 42
```

My question is: how does simply calling `Person.call(this, name, age)`
within the Employee constructor, result in the object having the `name` and `age` property when calling `new Employee(...)`

I understand that it's calling the Person function with the `this` being the context within `Employee` but It's not clear how the properties get onto the resulting object. What exactly is happening "under the hood?"

Comment: I'd suggest investing a lot of time studying JavaScript closures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Kris that has nothing to do with closure, it is just the nature of javascript which operates on "dynamic" `this` pointer which drives those who dont understand it crazy. That's why you can "borrow" functions in javascript, the popular pattern often seen is `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)` to convert a `NodeList` to an array before the addition of `Array.from`

Comment: This is because when the `new` instanceof `Employee` is called `Person` is called width it's `this` bound to the instanceof `Employee`.

Comment: @PHPglue I get why it occurs, but it's not clear how those properties get added to the instance. If you were to copy and paste the code into the JS console, simply running `Person.call(this, 'window', 1)` would not result in `name` or `age` properties added to the window. It's only when called within the context of a constructor function that the resulting object has the properties from another constructor function/object

Comment: It does work. `Person.call(this, 'window', 1); console.log(name);` you get `window`. `this` is in the global context like that.

Comment: @PHPglue You're right it does. However I'm still curious about what happens between the `Person.call(...)` call, and the properties being "placed" on the window/instance/etc. object.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4778408/878906

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that it's calling the `Person` function with the `this` being the context within `Employee`

Do you also understand what the "context within `Employee`" is? It's the new instance, the resulting object, that the `new` operator created before running the constructor function's body (`Employee` in `new Employee`). See [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572) for details.

> It's not clear how the properties get onto the resulting object. What exactly is happening "under the hood?"

The properties get created by the assignments:

```
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
…
this.employeeID = employeeID;
```

Again, `this` refers to the resulting object. In the former two cases, because [the `call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) was explicitly used on `Person`, in the latter case because `new` was used on `Emloyee`.

Answer (score 2):

Within the method of an Object the `this` context belongs to the Object's context. In the case of `Person`, it is an `instanceof Function`, which has it's `this` context bound to the global context *(`window` in Client Side JavaScript)*. A `new` instance creates a `new` *(independent with the exception of it's prototype inheritance)* Object and the `this` context is bound to it. `new` instances also return `this` if a return value is not specified. This should also explain why the `this` context in an EventListener is attached to the Object to which it belongs... the Element.

To daisy chain your instance methods, it's a common practice to `return this;` within them.